# How to add contents to YAML file using ruamel.yaml?

Tags: python, ruamel.yaml

Here is the input.yml file

```
PRODUCT_HOME: /app
config: 
  active-profiles: mysql,oauth2
  driverClassName: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
  datasourceurl: jdbc:h2:file:./data
  datasourceuser: sa
server:
  error:
    path: /error
  whitelabel:
    enabled: false
  port: 8080
```

Output file should look like:

```
PRODUCT_HOME: /app
config: 
  active-profiles: mysql,oauth2
  driverClassName: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
  datasourceurl: jdbc:h2:file:./data
  datasourceuser: sa
server:
   error:
      path: /error
   whitelabel:
      enabled: false
   port: 8080
   servlet:
     session:
       cookie:
         secure: true
```

How can I achieve this using Python (ruamel.yaml) package?

Comment: In your output file your value for `config` is indented 2 positions, that for `server` three positions. `ruamel.yaml` normalizes that, but it should not make difference for any program processing the YAML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create the correct data structure for the data you want to add
and then add that datastructure to the mapping that is the value of `server`

```py
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

from pathlib import Path

in_file = Path('input.yaml')
    
nd = dict(servlet=dict(session=dict(cookie=dict(secure=True))))

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
data = yaml.load(in_file)
data['server'].update(nd)

# print(data)
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
PRODUCT_HOME: /app
config:
  active-profiles: mysql,oauth2
  driverClassName: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
  datasourceurl: jdbc:h2:file:./data
  datasourceuser: sa
server:
  error:
    path: /error
  whitelabel:
    enabled: false
  port: 8080
  servlet:
    session:
      cookie:
        secure: true
```

Alternatively, if you have the data to add as YAML input you can load that and
then update:

```py
yaml_str = """
servlet:
  session:
    cookie:
      secure: true
"""

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
nd = yaml.load(yaml_str)
data = yaml.load(in_file)
data['server'].update(nd)

# print(data)
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which also gives:

```
PRODUCT_HOME: /app
config:
  active-profiles: mysql,oauth2
  driverClassName: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
  datasourceurl: jdbc:h2:file:./data
  datasourceuser: sa
server:
  error:
    path: /error
  whitelabel:
    enabled: false
  port: 8080
  servlet:
    session:
      cookie:
        secure: true
```